# How to speed-up Log-sum-exp function over multidimensional R Arrays?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, xtensor

I am working on speeding up a program I wrote in R. The code involves repeatedly computing LogSumExp over multidimensional arrays, i.e computing  s_lnj = exp(u_lnj) / (1 + sum_k exp(u_lnk)). The base R version of the code I am trying to increase the speed of is the following:

```
log_sum_exp_func <- function(vec){
  max_vec <- max(vec)
  return(max_vec + log(sum(exp(vec-max_vec))))
}

compute_share_from_utils_func <- function(u_lnj){
  ### get dimensions
  L <- dim(u_lnj)[1]; n_poly <- dim(u_lnj)[2]; J <- dim(u_lnj)[3]
  
  ### compute denominator of share, 1 + sum exp utils
  den_ln <- 1 + exp(apply(u_lnj, c(1,2), log_sum_exp_func))
  den_lnj <- array(rep(den_ln, J), dim = c(L, n_poly, J))
  
  ### take ratio of utils and denominator
  s_lnj <- exp(u_lnj) / den_lnj
  return(s_lnj)
}
```

I tried to use xtensor and Rcpp to speed things up, but ran into several issues. The Rcpp code I wrote is the following

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(xtensor)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]
#include <numeric>                    // Standard library import for std::accumulate
#define STRICT_R_HEADERS              // Otherwise a PI macro is defined in R
#include "xtensor/xmath.hpp"          // xtensor import for the C++ universal functions
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"
#include "xtensor-r/rarray.hpp"       // R bindings
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double cxxlog_sum_exp_vec(xt::rarray<double>& m)
{
  auto shape_m = m.shape();
  double maxvec = xt::amax(m)[0];
  xt::rarray<double> arr_maxvec = maxvec * xt::ones<double>(shape_m);
  xt::rarray<double> vec_min_max = m - arr_maxvec;
  xt::rarray<double> exp_vec_min_max = xt::exp(vec_min_max);
  double sum_exp = xt::sum(exp_vec_min_max)[0];
  double log_sum_exp = std::log(sum_exp);
  return log_sum_exp + maxvec; 
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
xt::rarray<double> cxxshare_from_utils(xt::rarray<double>& u_lnj)
{
  int L = u_lnj.shape(0);
  int N = u_lnj.shape(1);
  int J = u_lnj.shape(2);
  xt::rarray<double> res = xt::ones<double>({L,N,J});
  for (std::size_t l = 0; l < u_lnj.shape()[0]; ++l)
  {
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < u_lnj.shape()[1]; ++n)
    {
      xt::rarray<double> utils_j = xt::view(u_lnj, l, n, xt::all());
      double inv_lse = 1 / (1 + std::exp(cxxlog_sum_exp_vec(utils_j)));
      for (std::size_t j = 0; j < J; ++j)
      {
        res(l, n, j) = std::exp(u_lnj(l, n, j)) * inv_lse;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

The Rcpp implementation does seem to yield the same results as the base R code, however it seems to encounter problems whenever the dimensions of the input array increase. My R Session fails if I run

```
L <- 100
n <- 100
J <- 200
u_lnj <- array(rnorm(L*n*J,0,2), dim = c(L, n, J))
test <- cxxshare_from_utils(u_lnj)
```

But the code runs fine for L, n, J = 10,10,20 for instance. Moreover, the C++ implementation of log_sum_exp does not seem to outperform the base R version that much.

EDIT: I could not figure out what was the issue with the way I am using xtensor. But I did get some speed up with the following RcppArmadillo code. The drawback of this version is that is likely not as robust to overflow as the base R function relying on Log Sum Exp.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cube cxxarma_share_from_utils(arma::cube u_lnj) {
  
  // Extract the different dimensions
  
  // Normal Matrix dimensions
  unsigned int L = u_lnj.n_rows;
  unsigned int N = u_lnj.n_cols;
  
  // Depth of Array
  unsigned int J = u_lnj.n_slices;
  
  //resulting cube
  arma::cube s_lnj = arma::exp(u_lnj);
  for (unsigned int l = 0; l < L; l++) {
    
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
      
      double den = 1 / (1 + arma::accu(s_lnj.subcube(arma::span(l), arma::span(n), arma::span())));
      
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < J; j++) {
        
        s_lnj(l, n, j) = s_lnj(l, n, j) * den;
      }
    }
  }
  return s_lnj;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow -- Maybe start by having a look at this question posted only two days ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242518/why-is-my-rcpp-mean-function-slower-than-r  Similar concerns apply here too.

Comment: Good morning Dirk, thank you for your reply. The link you sent suggests that there might not be much gains to be expected for logSumExp as it is already vectorized. But I guess where I was hoping to speed things up is the application logSumExp to 3D arrays. So far I have been using R apply function, but I was wondering whether Rcpp could provide something faster there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I find it hard to directly answer your question because the problem seems to be a segmentation fault (you said that you session stops suddenly). It often implies that you are going out of bounds somewhere. Steps to debug are to turn-on bounds checks in xtensor by defining `XTENSOR_ENABLE_ASSERT`, and/or to study a simplified pure C++ code for example using valgrid. Furthermore, you are raising to questions at the same time, which would be good to split. One question with simply getting your code to work, and one with the performance question.

Comment: Then, for the performance question, it seems that your two codes are not computing the same thing. The armadillo version does not seems to take the exponent and the log, which might explain why it is faster. Finally a comment, studying performance is usually done on large problems, with small problems you might be probing simply the interface between R and your library

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your comment. I think the performance issue is solved, that's why I edited the post. As you noted the Armadillo implementation dropped the exp(logSumExp) approach, which makes it less robust to overflow, but I don't think that will be an issue for my application. I am left with the problem with xtensor causing a segmentation fault. I switched to Armadillo because I could not get xtensor to work. I was also puzzled by the fact that the problem only seems to arise when I increase the dimensions of the input array.